# Convert comma separated string type series into a list of integers pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, series

[image: input csv file screenshot]

My pandas dataframe has a column(series) with comma separated string values looking like this:

```
col_1,col_2,col_3
abc,123,49
bcd,234,"39,48"
```

I want to convert this col_3 into a list of integers. I tried

```
df["col_3"]=[[i] for i in df["col_3"]]
```

But I end up getting this result

```
col_1,col_2,col_3
abc,123,['49']
bcd,234,"['39,48']"
```

The desired output is

```
col_1,col_2,col_3
abc,123,[49]
bcd,234,[39,48]
```

I also want it to be fast  because I would be using this for  batches of 100k rows.
Can some one suggest a solution . TIA

```
    col_1       col_2    col_3
0   F18  9994      495
1   C35  9995  390,483
3   F60  9998  497,468
```

Comment: Is the single value a string or an int initially?

Comment: string @KevinChoonLiangYew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.str.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with a list comprehension :

```
df['col_3'] = [[int(e) for e in x.split(",")] for x in df['col_3']]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

  col_1  col_2     col_3
0   abc    123      [49]
1   bcd    234  [39, 48]

print(type(df.loc[0, 'col_3'][0]))
int
```

##### # Edit :

If you need to save your `df` to a `.csv`, there will be always double quotes between all the lists of integers (with a length > 1) since the elements of a list is separated by a `comma` and the default separator of [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is the `comma` as well. Double quotes are there to escape the commas inside these lists. So, to get rid of the double quotes, you have to choose another separator like the `tab` for example :

```
df.to_csv(r'path_to_your_new_csv', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 2):

I am piggybacking on abokey's answer because they are already on the right track. Please let me know my dummy dataframe is not in your required format.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["F18", "C35"], "col2":[9994, 9995], "col3":[43, '"39,48"']})
```

Using `str.split` would seperate your string elements into a list of substrings, based on your delimiter. he benefir of the appraoch is the whole string is put in a list, when the delimiter cannot be found as in `df.loc[0, "col3"]`. Afterwards, we apply list comprehension to change dtype of each element from `str` to `int` since it is your preferred format.

```
df["col3"] = df["col3"].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in str(x).strip('"').split(",")])
```

Edit: I updated the values based on your screenshot. use `tqdm` to see the progress when you are running on 100k rows.

```
!pip install tqdm
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
df["col3"] = df["col3"].progress_apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in str(x).strip('"').split(",")])
```

I can recommend [pandarallel](https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/) to parallel process through rows but it does not always work in my experience.

```
!pip install pandarallel
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True, nb_workers=4)
df["col3"] = df["col3"].parallel_apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in str(x).strip('"').split(",")])
```

Comment: so close.. but when i convert to csv i get double quotes around col_3 whenever more than 1 value is present
C3,9999,"[390, 483]"
F6,9999,"[497, 468]"

Comment: Is this better? 
df["col3"] = df["col3"].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in str(x).strip('"').split(",")])

Comment: no. @abokey's answer is close but I end u with  double quotes around my list.